# Laravel response file problem in prevent back button history middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller, middleware, php-8

I am using Laravel, and I have created a PreventBack middleware to prevent users from returning to the page after logout.

**Middleware**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PreventBack
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        return $response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store,
                max-age=0, must-revalidate')
            ->header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            ->header('Expires', 'Sun, 02 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
    }
}
```

But I have a route that returns the profile image.

```
Route::get('/profileimage', function () {

    return response()->file(storage_path('profile_image.jpg'));
});
```

When I put my profile image route in preventing back middleware, this route stops working, and the route does not return the profile image.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['PreventBack']], function () {
    Route::get('/profileimage', function () {
        return response()->file(storage_path('profile_image.jpg'));
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using cache? disabling cache does not mean not access to route after logout.
Laravel has a built-in middleware that keeps route only accessible by authenticated users.
Use `auth` middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { Route::get('/profileimage', function () { return response()->file(storage_path('profile_image.jpg')); }); });
```